# Unable to connect to Notebook Instance in GCP through IAP tunneling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, in-app-purchase, ssh-tunnel, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have an **Owner** access to GCP project.We need to access a Notebook instance which does not have external ip , so its using IAP tunneling. I am able to access  the same but my team members who I have given  **IAP-Secured Tunnel User**  and have the **Notebook Viewer** access are NOT able to access and get the error in putty terminal

*No supported authentication methods available(server sent:public key)*.

As per google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding) the firewall rule should also be set for IAP which is NOT set for this instance. But if that's the issue how am I able to access and not others. Is there some other role need to be added ?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [Determine who has access to the JupyterLab instance](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new#determine_who_has_access_to_the_jupyterlab_instance): "Unless you granted access to a specific service account or a single user, anyone that has editor permissions to your Google Cloud project can access the notebook". You're able to connect because you have [Owner](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_roles) role permissions.

Comment: You can try to grant `Service Account User` or `Editor` role to your team members and ask them to try again.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue before which I fixed it from the screen below. You can click on add member button.

[image]

Can you try adding them and then if you are using cli, ask them to update the sdk before trying the command.

Hope this helps.